# how to insert cell based on column sort in excel

Tags: vba, excel

How can I insert a new cell with value in a specific position based on sorted column in excel?

As example if I have this sorted data in a column.

```
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdefg
abcdefgh
```

And I want to insert a new cell with value `abcdef` .

The result should be.

```
abc
abcd
abcde
"abcdef"
abcdefg
abcdefgh
```

How could to achieve that using `VBA` ?

Comment: Loop through the range and compare the string you want to insert with every cell until it is smaller.  Then insert a row and put your value in the empty cell.  Or just add it at the end and resort the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too believe that inserting new value at the original range end and sorting it all again is the way

here follows my code for that

```
Sub InsertSorted(rng As Range, newVal As String)
    With rng.EntireColumn
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).value = newVal
        .Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending
    End With
End Sub
```

to be exploited as follows

```
Sub main()
    InsertSorted ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), "abcdef" ' would also work with "Range("A:A")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add the new value on at the end, then resort the column:

```
Sub InsertSorted()
    NewCellValue = "abcdef"
    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Range("A:A").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = NewCellValue
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:A")
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

There are otherways to go about this, but I think this may be the simplest. If this doesn't work in your situation, let me know. There are other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing for you to do is to add your new string value to the first empty row, and then sort the column.  The following module will do this, with the `insertValue` variable specifying the text that you want to add.

```
Sub Sort()
    Dim insertValue As String
    insertValue = "ab"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set currentCell = Range("A1")
    Do While Not IsEmpty(currentCell)
      Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Range(currentCell.Address).Value = insertValue
    Range("A1").Sort key1:=Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This below loads data onto an array, determine where to insert, and then add the value and paste results back. No rows insertion, but once you have the index you can adapt the code.
Just tested this with a few cases and should be customizable further for your needs

```
Option Base 1
Sub insertString()

    Dim rgRange As Range
    strToInsert = Cells(1, 2).Value
    Set rgRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
    m = rgRange.Rows.Count

    Dim arArray() As String
    ReDim arArray(m)

'load data
    For i = 1 To m
        arArray(i) = rgRange(i, 1).Value
    Next i

'determine where add your string
    k = m + 1
    For i = 1 To m
        If strToInsert < arArray(i) Then
            k = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i


'shift all upper values +1
    m = m + 1
    ReDim Preserve arArray(m)
    g = k + 1
    For i = m To g Step -1
        arArray(i) = arArray(i - 1)
    Next i

'insert your string
    arArray(k) = strToInsert

'paste results overwriting previous range
    Set rgdest = Range(rgRange(1, 1), rgRange(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0))
    For i = 1 To rgdest.Rows.Count
        rgdest(i, 1).Value = arArray(i)
    Next i



End Sub
```